# How can i make my player continuously move when a button gets held down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make my player move to the left whenever a button gets held down, however when i tested my script in unity it only moves him one time. I want to make him continuously move, does anyone know how to fix this?

```
 public void LeftMove()//Gets called everytime my button is held down
{
    rb.AddForce(120 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your _full_ code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `MonoBehavior` for this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html?_ga=2.41628450.1679355400.1598170423-1757949218.1598170423

This is not an event you are looking for, so you need to check yourself every cycle if the key is pressed:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            rb.AddForce(120 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```